# mean.io 127.0.0.1:3000 can't access via external ip

Tags: node.js, firewall, centos7, mean.io

I'm currently running on Centos 7. The command netstat -tulpen shows this:
[image]

I have run gulp based on the tutorial in mean.io. I run curl http://localhost:3000/ which works fine. Everything is displayed in the localhost. But when i try to access it via external ip, it is not showing anything. Eg. http://192.168.0.127:3000/. I think it is something related to the firewall, but I have set it accordingly because I can access http://192.168.0.127:8080/ just fine. Just that I can't access anything that has the local address of 127.0.0.1:ports but I can access 0.0.0.0:ports
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're listening on the wrong network interface. `127.0.0.1` indicates that a daemon should listen on the *loopback* network interface, which does exactly what it sounds like - when traffic is sent to it, it will "loop back" to the same computer instead of being sent over the network. Because you're listening on the loopback interface, only traffic coming from the loopback interface (and thus, your local machine) will actually be sent to your daemon.

The solution is to bind to `0.0.0.0`. `0.0.0.0` indicates that the program should bind to *all* network interfaces, including your external interface. With that in place, traffic will be routed correctly to your daemon.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, how do you suggest me to bind it to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: @user2615039 depends. look around for where the address is specified. if you can't find it, it's probably the default somewhere. make a guess and then read the documentation.

Comment: @user2615039 if this answer helped you, it's polite to give an upvote by clicking the up arrow at the left of the answer. if it solved your problem, it's polite to accept it by clicking the checkbox right below the up- and down-arrows.

Comment: I wanted to vote but I don't have enough reputation to upvote.. sry